# Issues with running RayDP / Spark on Ray Client

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ray

[Current documentation on using RayDP with Ray Client](https://github.com/oap-project/raydp/blob/master/doc/spark_on_ray.md) only says: "RayDP works the same way when using ray client. However, spark driver would be on the local machine." It would be very helpful to have at least one example of how it should be configured and used.

Implementing with Ray v2.1.0 and RayDP v1.5.0 (using Azure Kubernetes Service as backend) something straight forward as:

```
ray.init(address="ray://raycluster-kuberay-head-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:10001")
spark = raydp.init_spark(app_name='RayDP Example',
                         num_executors=1,
                         executor_cores=1,
                         executor_memory='500M')
df = spark.createDataFrame([('look',), ('spark',), ('tutorial',), ('spark',), ('look', ), ('python', )], ['word'])
```

Initializes Ray Client, RayDP/PySpark and creates the dataset without errors, but then

```
df.show()
```

creates an endless stream of

```
[Stage 0:> (0 + 0) / 1]
2023-06-04 22:18:13,383 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl [task-starvation-timer]: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2023-06-04 22:18:28,382 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl [task-starvation-timer]: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2023-06-04 22:18:43,382 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl [task-starvation-timer]: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Although an approach with wrapping "init_spark" into a ray actor works fine.
Any advice or example to run remotely with Ray CLient will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.